# Invalid base64 string from Ruby controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

All I want to do is respond with a base64 string when this action on my controller is contactacted.

```
class V1::AppProxyController < ApplicationController

  def logo
    send_file("#{Rails.root}/public/fresh_modal.png", 
              type: "image/png", 
              disposition: "inline")
  end
```

But the response, when I put it into an online converter, does not return the image. Plus it has all those odd characters. What am I doing wrong?

```
"�PNG


IHDRZ
�*tEXtSoftwareAdobe ImageReadyq�e< iTXtXML:com.adobe.xmp<?xpacket begin="﻿" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?> <x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.0-c060 61.134777, 2010/02/12-17:32:00        "> <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"> <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/" xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/" xmlns:stRef="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ResourceRef#" xmp:CreatorTool="Adobe Photoshop CS5 Windows" xmpMM:InstanceID="xmp.iid:56A07D6E335911E7B92CC44F92F10C15" xmpMM:DocumentID="xmp.did:56A07D6F335911E7B92CC44F92F10C15"> <xmpMM:DerivedFrom stRef:instanceID="xmp.iid:56A07D6C335911E7B92CC44F92F10C15" stRef:documentID="xmp.did:56A07D6D335911E7B92CC44F92F10C15"/> </rdf:Description> </rdf:RDF> </x:xmpmeta> <?xpacket end="r"?>&���IDATx��Yy�]U��]�6�7K;��L�^���(aS*�����(U�H��A!`E�
Fb�&P ����S�Bי��v��0�[�g���w�yCJĶ�5��{������߹t�i�ȥA��U-�ќ%2$袙��9¥���vl��*Pu��fd�G�C�h�vn����ς�$��K����"q(?��$��˒�ȥ��%8�s^�4���h�  r�C[�'|�v�1)#��D������#���x�w�MO��
��C�����Q�H���y�������:�ʣ듮�pF��=��.RZ���?��t��'�Y�%����kZ#���|�&�wOx�B��N���љ�EȓG!��/�j�Q��̄c�q�j���gj�u�Չ��^��Z�%�T�q�S&��v��
i�l;
�A��>��#J�Ԁ��Kr���3^e��Q
 �2�u�(�
�H.�ڕ�ۑ�kѿQ�}2��"H�%$�!\n� wC��9�<kmyзX��:.�L��w��}��*���e�O�T[�ӣ�G�кCfֶ'#�����`p%�
5f��Q,���9�@������.Wb�{ E�x;~�dp+��07Ɇ��m�Z��D�b0<  :'�&���a��I���Z��zkM ������ wA.��
� �5����:�Bf�ޞ��y�-rVxal*!��+�s����v�|ځ�j��GÖ9ў<�Ga�єt(���bd���c;,�l���u���� � i�A{��Z�N��
M�����[�+>�{�ju�?N��y�Qu�Ċ��kv���Ha �S%!/@�Cx��G�����}Eu�"���!������(�mD��[�T���O��N��;v!�N�-�g"���Ӎ5r�}Wm�
�����.x�-�{-��ހ
���a�?#��.7J���7�~Zs�`jhS�J��ϋ��1��C�k��v�&�No]ek�lA\j��~pEz��)�r��؉����T&.x�>�   i����HRG^S�Ly
y: �2h�u8��Upj!j����x���D�(]�q�'6�6���\�����H|v䜊s+�r/dnٺn�Cx��x�����Y�w:R!i-��Z���W�~�vl���[(�ߣR��i�}���h[    "���n���8�;�{�W�]B�R�>�l�\9'��m�Cu�V���G��(=
W=6ӓm���
Қ��z�oH�Q����ꅢ
�!�,r���t��Tq�"�-thQ�F��h+�g�|���[8 �b���ƹ�
��k��z��Z�݌�sh�/��e�1YfD�
hJ���x����J9?���I)>B?]�Ov�TA"��B�|/��$�q�δ�cC�v�Խ��� ��ja�;�Q�㺫�R��\���z?�Xi�H��+)��m���獪��~�mU���wUT�V�2x=RBeh�V�&��KE�F���u��L4��P�fv������3Fw[�]*��N�    o���}��hq�,���kVa�F<6�8�A��AQ~�o��FF4���s�&8T1d��X*�(�6^��Ps�w�����@C���0R�z1M"�z�GUQDSD)I?��W)�N�}�a����:1�44}�~��2*��\o5�a�>�7�x�-����8�<�   mĻ�޹Ɩ�!���=�FG�����0������N�x��#!�t��C��w��M�;�JQ��2Rt{��e�H�v�q>�H�@Ͳ��FQ�ݾcvH��y���J���>�5c�!�&��x����J0�lҥ9��r�
4���q ��r=��y�����t��p���Ә=�g�*�Z�:���XO�(�    ��Qm���nJ���P���{��0���D3-j�C[�|g#��n�#���V����h*����5����i�?d%�u�R��B�    ߉����h��fG���,h��,�;��.�U��oJ��I
�����8�!�����������t̒{16��S�0�]���P�i�Ci����H��Fd
=�K��,��+����m��y�w$������[�F�G=?���a8�=�J�ل��0J�\����c��ӡ�zk�G��_-ݟ����5�S+��G���/΃l��)<8��;��=\��M��2�K��V�%���؃��x�\g�|��ay+��B8�QEX,R��G��h�,R_�"Cf�,���j�LFDbic#�v5��
G}rQ��:+]�_���P�b�>�L^*�X����LD��8DE��'Γ&>?
"����0<2gL:��YuL����|��"�
 7��~����Ɇ]]vY��Ts7�w8�\x�Dl�Ur<��eU~���)���g��&E7���n�On@�>��q�X+r��ZN��s�κ8DCj
G��HKن+�N�tg�V�Y�)_ڿc�-�r��3��5��B?���1`zvILa�Y���0v������k�=��ډ��(J�&������W@:{�[?�?�]�+[�����H�k�!�<�vf;��x�ڢ��&��-J��ǠÆE�"�+�5�4�^�yl   ���b�*��a�Ɠ�B����
i�!�����i�:����b����c��@�j��p$�����:->�}הNǓE)�h9�OB�e��Ü�3��腦��\S5ca�ɘ,�p�C�C��T8���nK���X6L���c?� �r���B-���i>�*�ǁ��͂�����W
_l��ȳ[ૻ��W6Sh���@��I����<��6�H{%2A��g��60��.��A��m0J?t'`�<�a,,m�x>��q�K[Z>   Z���'��.��y��5�M�� #ĝ�JₔSe��g����J��VtQ�^
��AyU�O�R[`FV*�U���d�A��K�a�S�����h�Gڑ���Y�?�б.�c)�1��~�_ƙ(S���IEND�B`�"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode the file to Base64 instead of returning the binary data

```rb
File.open("#{Rails.root}/public/fresh_modal.png", 'rb') do |img|
  base64_file = 'data:image/png;base64,' + Base64.strict_encode64(img.read)
end
render plain: base64_file
```